# Jade not rendering external JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I have a jade template that should list all possible solutions to the QPX Express search request:

```
{ kind: 'qpxExpress#tripsSearch',
  trips: 
   { kind: 'qpxexpress#tripOptions',
     requestId: 'RwDOf6HXVDvvn6nBm0PNpw',
     data: 
      { kind: 'qpxexpress#data',
        airport: [Object],
        city: [Object],
        aircraft: [Object],
        tax: [Object],
        carrier: [Object] },
     tripOption: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } }
```

However, I'm trying to render the above the view but I keep getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'tripOption' of undefined
```

Template

```
block content
  .ui
    for data in result
      .ui_box
        .ui_box__inner
          .event
            span #{data.trips.tripOption[].saleTotal}
```

Route

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  api.apiGet(function (data) {
    console.log(data) //THIS WORKS
    res.render('index', {result: data})
  })
})
```

All the code is looking right to me and I'm working off properties from the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/trips/search). Can anyone point me in the right direction to debug?

Answer (score 1):

**Update: 1**

To display `saleTotal` from array of `tripOption`, change your jade template like the below one,

```
block content
  .ui
    for data in result
      .ui_box
        .ui_box__inner
          .event
            each trip in data.trips.tripOption
            span #{trip.saleTotal}
```

---

In your code, `span #{data.trips.tripOption[].saleTotal}`

if `data` refers to JSON content then change your span bindings like this

`span #{data.trips.data.tripOption[].saleTotal}` 
else 
`span #{data.tripOption[].saleTotal}`

Because `tripOption` is avaiable in `data` object not in `trips`

Comment: Okay thanks that's great. I can access `tripOption` but I can't reach the nested object where `saleTotal` lives. I get the following error `Cannot read property 'saleTotal' of undefined`. Any ideas?